# How to analyze answer to the specific request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Here is my scenario:

- 5 users log in to the website which purpose is to shorten url links
  (like bilty.com or tiny.cc).
- Each user inputs a unique link and gets shortened result.

What I need to do is - to get some kind of analysis of this "shorten" request.

Also, I need to:

- see the output (the shortened link) in this analysis.
- check if the link was created or not.
- check if the shortened links are correct.
- make sure that the shortened link actually leads to the same website
  just like the corresponding link in the input.

EDIT: I deduced that it should be made via Response Assertion, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: You are providing full URL and it is making it short..Now, you need to validate that. Please provide more info about the analysis. What is meant by analysis?

Comment: Exactly, I need to validate that the shortened link actually equals to the input link.

Comment: I have to clarify - I need to make sure that the shortened link actually leads to the same website just like the corresponding link in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach1(Grey Out-1st Thread group):- Put two request in parallel. First is full and second is redirect. Check option redirect automatically in second http request which is redirecting. Now, put compare assertion and check. This takes lot of resource.

Approach2:-Put 2 HTTPs request in parallel. First is full HTTP request without any redirect and second HTTP request is for short url and having follow redirect option checked.
[image]
Then, use regex in both (two regex used) to fetch the URLs. Check option "apply on"-> sub-samples as show for short url sampler, if it is redirecting. Not required for sampler if there is no redirect. First sampler regex uses "apply on" as "Main Sample Only" as there is no redirect.
[image]
Last compare them in the JSR223 sampler to make last sample fail.

[image]
[image]
I have used JSR223 sampler. You can also choose to have other approach also for comparison.

Hope this helps.

**Update:-**

1. Assuming you have data in two columns in csv as shown below image. Go to bin>user.properties file and put sample_variables as two column names used in the csv. Please restart jmeter if already open after editing user.properties file.
   [image]
2. Put the first parameter in the http sampler.
   [image]
3. Put the assertion as dynamic using second variable from the csv.
   [image]
   Note:- Do check the options in assertion to get what is required in your scenario. Follow redirection and Redirect Automatically have difference which required different assertion "apply to":- Main Sample or Sub-Sample. Do check them, if required.
   Please check if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But, do you think I will be able to achieve this using only Response Assertion, without creating multiple HTTP requests? Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Yes you can do that if you have all the required data before hand to validate the redirection in csv. Then, you can use Response assertion.  Ex: URL A--Redirect-->URLB data in csv..we can put this in response assertion. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for and I do have a .csv file with all the links. I just don't know what exactly should I do in Response Assertion. Would be very greatful if you help me!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work, I'll try to explain why:

1. I can't change server name in step 2 because it breaks my scenario. Server name shall be the URL of the website which I work with (website which shortens links)

2. I already have a .csv file which contains URLs that should be shortened. I can't modify it, because it breaks my scenario as well (Shortening request stops working). I have shortened links in response data code. Maybe I can fetch them from there?

Comment: You can put the server name as static/hardcoded in Server name/IP like www.google.com and use dynamic part that is the part without domain/server name in "Path" field of HTTP sampler like ${path}..while sending it will become www.google.com/${path}. This is just another attempt but may be I am not getting your scenario correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I just figured out how to do it myself. What I've done:
I manually copied the shortened links from response body and put them in response assertion => patterns to test and toggled check mark on OR. Field to test - text response.

Now if shortened links do not match, this step fails.

Comment: Happy to hear that...:)